# Cannot resolve symbol 'get' in IDEA

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class rw2 {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
}
```

---

I haven't found any answers in internet. What wrong with it? How to resolve?

Comment: Is that the only error?

Answer (score 3):

Put `driver.get("https://www.google.com");` inside other method. Example:

```
public void openPage() {
    driver.get("https://wwww.google.com");
}
```

Now you're trying to call the `get` method from class context but you can't - it's not a static method.

Comment: To be pedantic, static methods cannot be called outside of a method either. Only declarations can be placed at the class level.